# Why does my search show all results with searching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I setup a search on my Products index page with [PgSearch](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) and [Will-Paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) like this:

**ProductsController**

```
def index
  @products = Product.text_search(params[:query]).page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
end
```

**Products Model**

```
 include PgSearch
 pg_search_scope :search, 

 def self.text_search(query)
   if query.present?
     search(query)
   else
     scoped
   end
 end
```

**Product index page**

```
<%= form_tag products_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
<% end %>

<% if @products.blank? %>
  No Results
<% else %>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>
   <%= product.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But the problem I'm having now is that when I go to the Product index page, it shows all of the products when I want it to show nothing until a search is done. If the search is blank, return **No Results** but when you first hit the page it should show nothing. How would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to only run a `text_search` when a search parameter is present. You can put this logic into the view, the controller, or in the model.

**In the view**

```
<% if params[:query].present? %>
  <% if @products.blank? %>
    No Results
  <% else %>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <%= product.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**In the controller**

```
def index
  if params[:query].present?
    @products = Product.text_search(params[:query]).page(params[:page]).per_page(5)
  else
    @products = Product.none # NOTE: Rails 4 only
  end
end
```

**In the model**

```
# create a new method to encapsulate this search logic then use it in the controller
def self.search(value)
  if value.present?
    Product.text_search(value)
  else
    Product.none # NOTE: Rails 4 only
  end
end
```

The old saying goes "fat model, skinny controller" so you might want to opt for the model method which will keep your controller and views simpler.

Comment: I'd like to suggest marking my answer as the accepted answer. Obviously not because it's mine but because having too many if/else is indeed bad practice. If the receiving view is expecting a collection, return one. It can either be an empty collection if there are no products or one with products in it.

Answer (score 1):

Put your display logic inside an if statement:

```
<% if params[:query].present? %>
  <% if @products.blank? %>
    No Results
  <% else %>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
      <%= product.name %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not familiar with how pg search works, you could do something like this in your method.

It's a nice refactoring as well as it avoids checking for existence and making decisions on params (code smell)

```
def self.text_search(query = "")
     search(query)
end
```

As I said, not sure how pg_search works. Maybe when you browse for nothing, it returns all records. If that's the case, you can just have it return an empty array. Something like this would do

```
 def self.text_search(query)
    return [] if query.nil?
    search(query)
 end
```